# I don't think I earned the "Teacher" badge

Tags: bug, stackexchange, badges

My first answer earned me three bronze badges, which was nice, but I don't feel that I deserved one of them:

> Teacher  Answer a question with score of 1 or more.

Either I made an error in parsing the language, or I was awarded this badge incorrectly. I say this because the question had a score of -2. My answer, happily, got a score of 1.

- If I made an error, and the "score of 1 or more" refers to the answer, I'd like to respectfully suggest that the text be changed to something like:

  > Post an answer with a score of 1 or more.
- Otherwise is there's a bug in the algorithm that awards badges?

Comment: The first bullet is it. Congrats, you legitimately earned the badge! I believe the wording would be system/network-wide though, making the rewording suggestion a good on-topic post on [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: I had and still have similar issues, not only on this website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text is ambiguous. Contrast the following two readings:

> Answer a, question with score of 1 or more.

> Answer a question, with score of 1 or more.

However a "teacher" is normally the person who gives knowledge to others. As such; the second reading, where your answer is the subject, is the correct reading. You also got awarded for the second.